# Wordpress and jquery autocomplete meta keys

Tags: jquery, wordpress, autocomplete, key, meta

I've been trying with no sucess to add a autocomplete in my wordpress.

In my **functions.php:**

```
 // Loads files with autocomplete
wp_register_script( 'jquery-ui', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-ui.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
 wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui');
wp_register_style( 'jquery-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-ui.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-style' );
wp_register_script( 'autocomplete-ui', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/autocomplete.js',  array( 'jquery') );
wp_localize_script( 'autocomplete-ui', 'autocomplete-object', array( 'url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
wp_enqueue_script( 'autocomplete-ui');
```

In my autocomplete.js

```
function ($) {
  'use strict';

$(function() {

$( "#busca" ).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        data:  {
             action: "autocompleteCallback",
             term: request.term
            },
         success: function (data) {

            }, }); } });   });   }(jQuery);
```

Back in my functions.php:

```
function acCallback() {
   global $wpdb;
   $search = $_REQUEST['term'];
   $query = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE postmeta.meta_value LIKE \'' . $search . '%\' AND post_type = \'NAME OF CUSTOM POST TITLE \'
AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'produto'" );

  $tab = array();
  foreach ($query->posts as $p):
    $tab[] =array('value'=>$p->postmeta.meta_value);
        endforeach;

          echo(json_encode($tab));
          exit;
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_autocompleteCallback', 'acCallback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_autocompleteCallback', 'acCallback' );
```

Nothing appears in my autocomplete... What is my mistake? Thanks for any help

Comment: And where is the AJAX URL? I guess you need to tell AJAX what to call.

Comment: Ok. I did it, but still not working:

Comment: $( "#busca" ).autocomplete({
 source: function( request, response ) {
 $.ajax({
  url : autocomplete-object.ajax_url,

Answer (score 0):

I GOT IT! I had to make some changes, but the main thing was:

IN my autocomplete.js

```
....
success: function (data) {
    response($.map(data, function(item) {
    return {
    value: item.meta_value,
    id :item.meta_id
    };
     }));
    };
```

And in my functions.php:

```
global $wpdb;
   $search = $_GET['term'];
    $query = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT DISTINCT meta_id, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='NAME OF META KEY' AND meta_value LIKE '".$search."%' " );


$suggestions = array();
foreach($query as $row) {
    array_push($suggestions, array(
            'meta_value' => $row->meta_value,
            'meta_id' => $row->meta_id
        )
    );
}
echo json_encode( $suggestions );
exit();
```